# Openlayer distors vector shapes

Tags: shapes, openlayers-3, distortion

I have a problem with drawing my vector shapes - when I zoom enough, it looks like some coordinates are skipped and the shape gets distorted - see the attached picture:

[image]

The shape is loaded from geojson file, where it's defined like:

```
"coordinates":[[[18.58235,49.81784],[18.58545,49.81738],[18.59252,49.81296]
,[18.59279,49.80395],[18.59986,49.79953],[18.60013,49.79051]
,[18.60719,49.78609],[18.61425,49.78168],[18.61093,49.7663]
,[18.07565,49.432],[18.07509,49.43198],[18.06119,49.43289]
,[18.04734,49.43411],[18.03356,49.43564],[18.01987,49.43747]
,[18.00628,49.4396],[17.99281,49.44204],[17.98218,49.44422]]]
```

Any idea, what's wrong?

Marek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your polygon geometry is invalid. You have to add another coordinate pair at the end, with the same values as the first coordinate pair:

```
"coordinates":[[[18.58235,49.81784],[18.58545,49.81738],[18.59252,49.81296]
    ,[18.59279,49.80395],[18.59986,49.79953],[18.60013,49.79051]
    ,[18.60719,49.78609],[18.61425,49.78168],[18.61093,49.7663]
    ,[18.07565,49.432],[18.07509,49.43198],[18.06119,49.43289]
    ,[18.04734,49.43411],[18.03356,49.43564],[18.01987,49.43747]
    ,[18.00628,49.4396],[17.99281,49.44204],[17.98218,49.44422]
    ,[18.58235,49.81784]]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's it!